# yii2 custom validation addError message doesn't show

Tags: yii2, dynamic-forms

when i use custom validations on yii2 dynamic forms it doesn't show any error messages below the input field.Below I have posted my model.
It doesn't show any error messges when qty field gets validated

namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

class OrderD extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'order_d';
}


public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['item_id', 'qty', 'price', 'value'], 'required'],
        [['item_id'], 'integer'],
        [['price', 'value'], 'number'],
        [['order_code'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
        [['item_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Item::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['item_id' => 'id']],
        [['order_code'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => OrderH::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['order_code' => 'code']],
        ['qty', 'validateQty']
    ];
}

public function validateQty($attribute)
{
    $qty = $this->$attribute;
    if ($qty >= 5)
    {
        $this->addError('qty', "qty validation successful");
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'item_id' => 'Item ID',
        'order_code' => 'Order Code',
        'qty' => 'Qty',
        'price' => 'Price',
        'value' => 'Value',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getItem()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Item::className(), ['id' => 'item_id']);
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getOrderCode()
{
    return $this->hasOne(OrderH::className(), ['code' => 'order_code']);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to know custom validations are php functions and not convert as javascript to validate in runtime .. those will work after the page has submit and send to controller ..

here is simple sample you want :

```
              ['qty','custom_function_validation'],



        ];
    }



 public function custom_function_validation($attribute, $params){
     if($this->$attribute>5){
        $this->addError($attribute,'it\'s more than 5');
     }
}
```

Comment: yes i know that but i want to send an ajax request to the controller and the trigger the validation but the ajax request doesn't seem to be sending

Answer (score 0):

To create a validator that supports client-side validation, you should implement the yii\validators\Validator::clientValidateAttribute() method which returns a piece of JavaScript code that performs the validation on the client-side.

```
public function clientValidateAttribute($model, $attribute, $view)
{
    return <<<JS
// your validation
JS;
}
```

See the documentation here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#implementing-client-side-validation

Comment: can't we use inline validatiors that sends an ajax request to the controller and get the error message

Comment: You should then disable client validation and enable ajax validation, or enable ajax validation for that specific field. Make sure you have logic in your controller action that handles the ajax validation (or custom validation URL that does the same)

Comment: I have enabled ajax validation and its working now @MaartenvanMiddelaar

Answer (score 0):

Use method addError() in a controller and then just render your view file

### Example

```
    if ($promo_code) {
        if ($promo_code->status == '1') {
            $message = 'This combination is incorrect.';
            $model->addError('promo_code', $message);
            return $this->render('index', compact('model'));
        }
        $promo_code->status = '1';
        $promo_code->save();
        $model->save();
    }
```